# Trouble connecting Flutter frontend with Django backend through API

Tags: django, flutter, dart, mobile, frontend

I am working on the frontend project using Flutter, and I am trying to connect it to the Django backend using API, I am completely lost on how to do that, can anyone help me, I would appreciate your help. I am very new to Flutter. We have implemented all the APIs with the Django REST framework.

Here is my front-end code for the register page, this code is using Dart language.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import './register2.dart';

class MyClip extends CustomClipper<Rect> {
  Rect getClip(Size size) {
    return Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 100, 100);
  }

  bool shouldReclip(oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}

class Avatar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Avatar> createState() => _AvatarState();
}

class _AvatarState extends State<Avatar> {
  File? image;
  Future pickImage() async {
    try {
      final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if (image == null) return;
      final imageTemp = File(image.path);
      setState(() => this.image = imageTemp);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print('Failed: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: image != null
          ? ClipOval(
              child: Image.file(
                image!,
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            )
          : Image.asset('assets/images/icon_sample.jpeg'),
    );
  }
}

class Regfirst extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var bg = 'assets/images/bg.jpeg';
    return Material(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(bg),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Container(
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              Positioned(
                top: 0,
                height: 400,
                width: 330,
                child: Avatar(),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 350,
                height: 300,
                width: 330,
                child: Column(
                  //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 3,
                            child: TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                hintText: "First name",
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 25,
                                ),
                                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 24, color: Colors.white),
                                border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 40),
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 3,
                            child: TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                hintText: "Last name",
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 25,
                                ),
                                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 24, color: Colors.white),
                                border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 3,
                            child: TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                hintText: "Email",
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 25,
                                ),
                                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 24, color: Colors.white),
                                border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 40),
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 3,
                            child: TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                hintText: "Phone number",
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 25,
                                ),
                                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 24, color: Colors.white),
                                border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 3,
                            child: TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                hintText: "Password",
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 25,
                                ),
                                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 24, color: Colors.white),
                                border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 3,
                            child: TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                hintText: "Confirm Password",
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 25,
                                ),
                                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 24, color: Colors.white),
                                border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 680,
                height: 45,
                width: 250,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  // color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Regsec()));
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'Next',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, a good starting point is this page: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data  - If you show us something you have already programmed and have questions about the code, then we can help you more precisely :D